# Merging/joining multiple data frames on 2 common columns which are not one-to-one

Tags: python, pandas, mapping, inner-join, data-cleaning

Suppose I have multiple data frames (e.g. 10+) which all have 3 common columns, namely 'code', 'desc', and 'date'. They are of type int, str, and datetime respectively. I would like to inner join all of these data frames on these 3 common columns, and retain as much data as possible.

In reality, 'code' and 'desc' should be a one-to-one mapping, however because of unclean data this is not the case. And within each data frame on any given date, the relationship between 'code' and 'desc' can be different. For example, on 'date' = 01/01/23, df1 has 2 rows `{'code': [123, 456], 'desc': ['product_A', 'product_A']}`, whereas df2 has 1 row `{'code': [123], 'desc': ['product_A']}`.

However, there is always a one-to-many mapping from 'desc' (one) to 'code' (many).

How do I get around this issue? Please note that I cannot just join on 'desc' and 'date' only (and forget 'code'). I need to inner join on all 3.

**My attempt at a solution:**

I have a function which takes a data frame as its input, and makes the 'code' and 'desc' columns one-to-one by replacing all 'codes' by their latest occurrence in the data frame, i.e. for each 'desc', this is the 'code' associated with the latest 'date' value.

This works except for when the latest 'desc' and 'date' occurrence has 2 rows, e.g. {'code': [123, 456], 'desc': ['product_A', 'product_A']}. Because then changing all 'code' values to 123 is just as valid as changing them all to 456, potentially leading to inconsistent mappings across each data frame.

But have I even gone about solving this the right way? Is there a more elegant/fail-safe solution such that I retain as much data as possible when inner-joining?

Reproducible input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'code': [123, 456, 123], 'desc': ['product_A', 'product_A', 'product_A'], 'date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2022-01-01']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'code': [123, 789], 'desc': ['product_A', 'product_B'], 'date': ['2023-01-01', '2022-01-01']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'code': [123, 456, 789], 'desc': ['product_A', 'product_A', 'product_B'], 'date': ['2023-01-01', '2023-01-01', '2022-01-01']})
```

Potential outputs:

```
Either:

pd.DataFrame({'code': [[123, 456], 789], 'desc': ['product_A', 'product_B'], 'date': ['2023-01-01', '2022-01-01']})

Or:

pd.DataFrame({'code': [123, 789], 'desc': ['product_A', 'product_B'], 'date': ['2023-01-01', '2022-01-01']})

Or something else (depending on what the best practice here is, row 1 of 'code' is different)
```

Comment: You question is not fully clear, you mention 10+ dataframes but only show 2, please add at least a third one to improve the example. Also please provide your current code and the expected output so we can see what is going wrong.

Comment: @mozway What else do you need to know about the data frames other than they all contain 3 columns 'ds', 'code' and 'desc', and their dtypes? It seems superfluous to show all of the columns of each data frame, especially when the examples are mock data which I am using as a stand-in instead of sensitive data. There is also nothing wrong with my code, I am just struggling with the strategy here.

Comment: We need a concrete example and the matching expected output, I currently don't understand what you want. Don't show all columns, but show enough to have a meaningful example. You mention 3 but show 2, you mention 10+ dataframes but only show 2 (hard to know how you want to generalize your merge with only 2). And most importantly you failed to provide the expected output (and your current code).

Comment: @mozway I have done my best to provide this, but the essence of my question is that am not exactly sure what the expected output/best practice should be in this situation. If I knew the expected output I would be able to write the code.

Comment: Then look at my proposed answer and see if this makes sense to you

Answer (score 1):

You can [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) all your dataframes, [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), then [`groupby.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
out = (pd
  .concat([df1, df2, df3])
  .drop_duplicates() # optional
  .groupby('desc', as_index=False)
  .agg({'code': lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x)),
        'date': 'max'})
)
```

Output:

```
         code       desc        date
0  [123, 456]  product_A  2023-01-01
1       [789]  product_B  2022-01-01
```

Or for the row of the last date, use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
out = (pd
  .concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=True)
  .astype({'date': 'datetime64'})
  .loc[lambda d: d.groupby('desc')['date'].idxmax()]
)
```

Output:

```
   code       desc       date
0   123  product_A 2023-01-01
4   789  product_B 2022-01-01
```